# WebService retorna um Array, e não estou conseguindo inserir em um Array<MinhaClasse>

Tags: java, json

```
{
 "cemaden":[
  {
     "codestacao":"520310401A",
     "latitude":-16.196,
     "longitude":-52.546,
     "cidade":"BALIZA",
     "nome":"Setor Central",
     "tipo":"Pluviom\u00E9trica",
     "uf":"GO",
     "chuva":0.0,
     "nivel":null,
     "dataHora":"2015-05-05 11:00:00.0"
  },
  {
     "codestacao":"520310401A",
     "latitude":-16.196,
     "longitude":-52.546,
     "cidade":"BALIZA",
     "nome":"Setor Central",
     "tipo":"Pluviom\u00E9trica",
     "uf":"GO",
     "chuva":0.2,
     "nivel":null,
     "dataHora":"2015-05-05 11:10:00.0"
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

Este é o retorno do webservice.

E estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
public String sendGet(String site) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(site);
    HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conexao.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(input);
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while((inputLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    input.close();

    return response.toString();
}

public void arrayPluviometros() throws Exception {
    String json = sendGet("http://150.163.255.240/CEMADEN/resources/parceiros/GO/1");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Pluviometro t = g.fromJson(json, Pluviometro.class);
    Type pluviometroType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Pluviometro>>() {}.getType();                
    List<Pluviometro> p = g.fromJson(json, pluviometroType);
}
```

E ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 1):

A resposta que você está obtendo é um objeto JSON e não um array de objetos. Este erro acontece por que é esperado um array no início do JSON (iniciando com `[`), uma vez que você passa como tipo para deserializar uma lista de `Pluviometro`, mas há um `{`, ou seja, o início de um objeto.

Há algumas formas de você fazer isto, irei citar apenas duas.

A forma mais simples é você definir um outro objeto, vamos chamá-lo de `CEMADENResponse` que agregará uma lista de pluviômetros. Como na resposta o nome do objeto é `cemaden`, para ficar mais legível o objeto precisamos falar o nome o atributo ao GSON. Então este objeto deve se parecer com isto:

```
public class CEMADENResponse {

    @SerializedName("cemaden")
    private List<Pluviometro> pluviometros;

    // getter e setter

}
```

Você pode chamar a lista de `cemaden` e não `pluviometros`, caso queira, e remover a anotação [`@SerializedName`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html), se assim preferir.

Criado o objeto, para deserializar para uma instância de `CEMADENResponse`, basta fazer algo assim:

```
final String jsonResponse = sendGet("http://150.163.255.240/CEMADEN/resources/parceiros/GO/1");
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final CEMADENResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, CEMADENResponse.class);
```

Daí basta recuperar a lista de pluviômetros e fazer o que você precisa, por exemplo imprimir o valor de todos eles:

```
final List<Pluviometro> pluviometros = response.getPluviometros();
for (Pluviometro pluviometro : pluviometros) {
    System.out.println("codestacao: " + pluviometro.getCodestacao());
    System.out.println("latitude: " + pluviometro.getLatitude());
    System.out.println("longitude: " + pluviometro.getLongitude());
    // outros atributos
}
```

Que gerará algo como isto de acordo com o resultado:

```
codestacao: 520310401A
latitude: -16.196
longitude: -52.546
```

A segunda forma é usar um deserializador customizado. Partindo da sua tentativa de retornar logo uma lista de pluviômetros, vamos fazer com que o deserializador customizado retorne então uma `List<Pluviometro>`.

O trabalho aqui é um pouco maior, pois devemos pegar o elemento `JSON` e ler cada propriedade. Deverá ser algo como isto:

```
public class PluviometroDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Pluviometro>> {

    @Override
    public List<Pluviometro> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final List<Pluviometro> result = new ArrayList<>();

        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        final JsonElement cemaden = jsonObject.get("cemaden");
        final JsonArray pluvs = cemaden.getAsJsonArray();

        final int pluvsSize = pluvs.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < pluvsSize; i++) {
            final JsonObject element = pluvs.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

            final Pluviometro pluv = new Pluviometro();
            pluv.setCodestacao(element.get("codestacao").getAsString());;
            pluv.setLatitude(element.get("latitude").getAsDouble());
            pluv.setLongitude(element.get("longitude").getAsDouble());
            // demais atributos

            result.add(pluv);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Ou seja, primeiro recuperamos o objeto `cemaden`, que é um [`JsonObject`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html). Como sabemos que nele há um array de pluviômetros, podemos recuperar um [`JsonArray`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html). Depois disto, basta recuperarmos cada elemento (que é a representação `JSON` do objeto `Pluviometro`) e recuperar seus atributos.

Desta forma, ao deserializar, você já irá obter diretamente a lista de pluviômetros, fazendo algo assim:

```
final String jsonResponse = sendGet("http://150.163.255.240/CEMADEN/resources/parceiros/GO/1");
final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Pluviometro>>() {}.getType();
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(type, new PluviometroDeserializer()).create();
final List<Pluviometro> pluviometros = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, type);;
for (final Pluviometro pluviometro : pluviometros) {
    System.out.println("codestacao: " + pluviometro.getCodestacao());
    System.out.println("latitude: " + pluviometro.getLatitude());
    System.out.println("longitude: " + pluviometro.getLongitude());
    // demais atributos
}
```

Isto também irá gerar algo como o exemplo anterior:

```
codestacao: 520310401A
latitude: -16.196
longitude: -52.546
```

Então, use a abordagem que considerar melhor ao seu contexto.

**Observação**: Estou usando a versão `2.3.1` nos exemplos, caso dê algum erro por aí, verifique a versão da biblioteca que está usando.

**EDIÇÃO**: incluindo solução para o erro do formato de data

A data no retorno esta vindo desta forma: `2015-05-05 11:00:00.0`. Para construir uma instância de [`Gson`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) utilize este padrão: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Um exemplo seria assim:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
```

Observei que no retorno os milissegundos são sempre *zerados*, mas caso você queira eles também, poderá usar como padrão este aqui: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`.

Comment: @AfonsoOliveiraNeto caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado, considere aceitá-la. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O brother, deu certo e resolveu o erro que estava... Porém surgiu um novo erro:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2015-05-17 13:00:00.0
>       at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)

Tentei o código abaixo porém também não resolveu:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
```

Comment: Afonso ao contrário de criar uma resposta, você pode fazer comentários na pergunta ou nas resposta. Quanto a este erro, é o formato da data que está errado. Considere remover esta pergunta e, caso tenha ajudado, aceitar a resposta que foi feita. Caso outros problemas tenham aparecido, considere criar uma nova pergunta que represente o que você evoluiu e o novo erro.

Comment: Desculpem a minha ignorância em relação a uma nova resposta em vez de comentário... Mas em relação ao erro da data, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: @AfonsoOliveiraNeto editei minha resposta com o formato de data adequado, conforme havia falado em comentário anterior o padrão de data está errado. Caso a resposta tenha ajudado, considere aceitá-la. Também, prefira fazer comentários em minha resposta, desta forma sou avisado que houve um comentário.